# Android Image Slider with half previous and next image?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

i want to show slider like that can any body help me  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVqK5.jpg.
i want to show slider with half previous and next image.

Comment: Use `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Just use RecyclerView with horizontal linear layout manager

Comment: Use `ViewPager` with page margin.

Comment: i just want to slide auto static images.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is these two libraries:

[Card Slider](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7856)

[Android-CoverFlow](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3530)

I hope to be useful ;)